# Div fading in and out

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, fadeout

I need your help, I am working on a website where I want a div to delay for 2 seconds then fade in when another div is clicked, but when I want to click it again (to close it) I want it to fade out instantly. Any help?

Comment: Try to use jQuery library: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Jquery, the following code will help you do it as i got what you want:
this is default css:

```
.invisElem{display:none}
```

and the jquery code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.boxbutton1', function(){
        var counter = $(this).data('count');
        if(counter == undefined){
            counter = 0;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.gymtext').fadeIn(500)//fadeIn after 2 seconds(2000 ms)
            }, 2000);
        }
        else if(counter == 0){
            $('.gymtext').fadeOut(function(){
                $('.gymtext').remove()
            });//fadeout quickly then remove
        }
    })
```

i tried to write it down novice friendly if you needed help add comment

Comment: Could you edit this for me please, its '.boxbutton1' that I want to click and i want '.gymtext' to be fading, thank you

Comment: its done. please consider accepting the right answer :D! and feel free to ask if there was a problem

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, Shall I send you the whole code?

Comment: you can send it to: homamghassemy@gmail.com

Comment: Any luck with it? I sent it to that email

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div").fadeToggle(240);
      });
    });
    </script>

<button>Click to fade DIV</button>

<div id="div" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Comment: This is sort of what im after, but i need it to delay when the button is clicked a second time, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show div1 and hide div2</a></div>

<div id="div1">Div1</div>
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
```

Css:

```
 #div2 {display:none;}
```

Jquery:

```
  $('#btn').click(function(e){    
$('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#div2').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

});

Comment: when you click on the `#btn` `#div1` fadesout then `#div2` fades in? its a complete reverse function, and where is the 2 seconds?